# Troubles to connect to Siemens S7 probably cause of bad protocol used

Tags: vb.net, libnodave

I encounter many troubles to connect to the PLC, for that, I use the libnodave library.

Here are the last informlations I got :
CPU 412-2
Communication : CP 443-1

So far, I manage to connect to the automaton, but, if I use the 
- UserTransport protocol, my programs crashes when I try to read a datum
- ISOTPC or MPI protocols, I can't connect to the PLC ...

So far, my code isn't so different with this one : http://www.automation-sense.com/medias/images/source-code-and-example-visual-basic-libnodave.jpg

In my case, the port number is 25, the rack value is 0 and the slot value is 3.

What may you suggest me to do?

Thanks

Comment: Please take some time to learn [How-to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve]. That way we will be able to help you better...

Comment: Many thanks for your help but I finally understaood my problem, actually, my own is not able to connect to their automaton... Moreover, I gave up the libnodave library to use the S7 library instead